# How do I find $\theta$ with bootstrap?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, order-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have two vectors of known values $x$ and $y$. And the relationship between them is
$y=\sin(\theta \cdot x)+\epsilon$,    $\epsilon \sim N(0,1) $  .
The question is how do I estimate $\theta$ with bootstrap?

I tried to create an inverse function for $\theta$: $\theta=\arcsin(\epsilon-y)/x$.
But for some data, $\epsilon -y$ can be larger then 1, so $\arcsin$ gives NAN.

What should I do?

Comment: I do not see how you can know $\epsilon-y$ is larger then $1$, since you only observe $x$ and $y$. But if it was the case  then your model relationship $y=\sin(\theta\cdot x)+\epsilon$ would be false.

Comment: I correct my mistake thanks. But the model is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap is not an estimation procedure, per se. It is a method for approximating sampling distributions. What you need is an estimation procedure. I would recommend Maximum Likelihood Estimation:

Given $\theta$ and $x$, we know that $y\sim \mathcal{N}(\sin{\theta x},1)$. What we want to do is maximize the likelihood of observing the $n$ values of $y_i$ *given* the associated $x_i$ by varying the value of $\theta$.

The log-likelihood of the above data is: $\mathcal{L}(\theta|(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})) = -\frac{n\ln{2\pi}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (y_i-\sin{\theta x_i})^2$.

The score function is: $S(\theta|(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})) = -\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \{ x_iy_i\cos{\theta x_i}+x_i\theta \cos(2\theta x_i)\}$

You will need to solve for $S(\theta|(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})) =0$ Bootstrapping is more for gauging the accuracy of such an estimator. If you coded an optimzation routine to solve for $\theta$ as decribed above, you would be able to determine an approximate confidence interval via bootstrapping. However, you need an estimator *first*.

Comment: I found the estimator by Newton-Raphson, $\theta$ = 1.72.          I create a vector $\epsilon$=y-sin(1.721218$\cdot$x), and now i Bootsrap from the vector $\epsilon$. But it's still gives me NAN.

Comment: @dmitriy to use boostrapping, you need to resample (x,y) pairs from your dataset and *re-estimate* $\theta$ using Newtown-Raphson. This will give you a bootstrap estimate, $\theta_i^*$. Perform this for N boostrap samples. The distribution of ($\theta_i^*$ - 1.72) is the bootstrap distribution of sampling errors.

Comment: @Glen_b ahh...there's one in every group ;-) Typo corrected.